# chart.js: Show labels outside pie chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

*chart.js 2.6.0*

I need to render a chart that looks like this:

[image]

Always showing all tooltips is not an acceptable way, since they won't get rendered in a proper manner:

[image]

Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution yet. I've tried the *piece-label* plugin, but this has the same problems, since it's labels overlap and I can't hide certain labels.

Here is the code, that creates my chart using *piece-label* to position the labels above the slices:

```
private createStatusChart(): void {
    const chartData = this.getStatusChartData();

    if (!chartData) {
        return;
    }

    const $container = $(Templates.Dashboard.ChartContainer({
        ContainerID: 'chart-status',
        HeaderText: 'Status'
    }));

    this._$content.append($container);

    const legendOptions =
        new Model.Charts.LegendOptions()
            .SetDisplay(false);

    const pieceLabelOptions =
        new Model.Charts.PieceLabelOptions()
            .SetRender('label')
            .SetPosition('outside')
            .SetArc(true)
            .SetOverlap(true);

    const options =
         new Model.Charts.Options()
             .SetLegend(legendOptions)
             .SetPieceLabel(pieceLabelOptions);

    const chartDefinition = new Model.Charts.Pie(chartData, options);
    const ctx = this._$content.find('#chart-status canvas').get(0);

    const chart = new Chart(ctx, chartDefinition);
}

private getStatusChartData(): Model.Charts.PieChartData {
    if (!this._data) {
        return;
    }

    const instance = this;
    const data: Array<number> = [];
    const labels: Array<string> = [];
    const colors: Array<string> = [];

    this._data.StatusGroupings.forEach(sg => {
        if (!sg.StatusOID) {
            data.push(sg.Count);
            labels.push(i18next.t('Dashboard.NoStateSet'));
            colors.push('#4572A7');

            return;
        }

        const status = DAL.Properties.GetByOID(sg.StatusOID);

        data.push(sg.Count);
        labels.push(status ? status.Title : i18next.t('Misc.Unknown'));
        colors.push(status ? status.Color : '#fff');
    });

    const dataset = new Model.Charts.Dataset(data).setBackgroundColor(colors);

    return new Model.Charts.PieChartData(labels, [dataset]);
}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the code you already have?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209074/how-to-move-labels-position-on-chart-js-pie

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans I've added the code that is responsible for the chart itself. The classes I'm using are just wrappers for the options.

Comment: Have you tried setting .SetArc(false), or removing it, does that make the output more like what you would like?

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't help. The problem is the overlapping of the labels of small slices - which wouldn't get better on small devices.

Comment: Does [potatopeelings' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36218682/1009922), suggested above by @bunzab, solve your problem? If not, what is missing?

Answer (score 10):

There is a new plugin (since a year),
called [chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels)

Just import the source  
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels"></script>`

 and use it with the outlabeledPie type

```
var randomScalingFactor = function() {
return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
};
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
var myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'outlabeledPie',
data: {
labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May"],
...
plugins: {
        legend: false,
        outlabels: {
           text: '%l %p',
           color: 'white',
           stretch: 45,
           font: {
               resizable: true,
               minSize: 12,
               maxSize: 18
           }
        }
     }
})
```

Answer (score 6):

I can't find an exact plugin but I make one.

```
      const data = {
        labels: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
        datasets: [
          {
            data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
            backgroundColor: [
              "#316065",
              "#1A7F89",
              "#2D9CA7",
              "#2D86A7",
              "#1167A7",
              "#142440",
            ],
            borderColor: [
              "#316065",
              "#1A7F89",
              "#2D9CA7",
              "#2D86A7",
              "#1167A7",
              "#142440",
            ],
          },
        ],
      };

      // pieLabelsLine plugin
      const pieLabelsLine = {
        id: "pieLabelsLine",
        afterDraw(chart) {
          const {
            ctx,
            chartArea: { width, height },
          } = chart;

          const cx = chart._metasets[0].data[0].x;
          const cy = chart._metasets[0].data[0].y;

          const sum = chart.data.datasets[0].data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

          chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset, i) => {
            chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach((datapoint, index) => {
              const { x: a, y: b } = datapoint.tooltipPosition();

              const x = 2 * a - cx;
              const y = 2 * b - cy;

              // draw line
              const halfwidth = width / 2;
              const halfheight = height / 2;
              const xLine = x >= halfwidth ? x + 20 : x - 20;
              const yLine = y >= halfheight ? y + 20 : y - 20;

              const extraLine = x >= halfwidth ? 10 : -10;

              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(x, y);
              ctx.arc(x, y, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
              ctx.fill();
              ctx.moveTo(x, y);
              ctx.lineTo(xLine, yLine);
              ctx.lineTo(xLine + extraLine, yLine);
              // ctx.strokeStyle = dataset.backgroundColor[index];
              ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
              ctx.stroke();

              // text
              const textWidth = ctx.measureText(chart.data.labels[index]).width;
              ctx.font = "12px Arial";
              // control the position
              const textXPosition = x >= halfwidth ? "left" : "right";
              const plusFivePx = x >= halfwidth ? 5 : -5;
              ctx.textAlign = textXPosition;
              ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
              // ctx.fillStyle = dataset.backgroundColor[index];
              ctx.fillStyle = "black";

              ctx.fillText(
                ((chart.data.datasets[0].data[index] * 100) / sum).toFixed(2) +
                  "%",
                xLine + extraLine + plusFivePx,
                yLine
              );
            });
          });
        },
      };
      // config
      const config = {
        type: "pie",
        data,
        options: {
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          layout: {
            padding: 30,
          },
          scales: {
            y: {
              display: false,
              beginAtZero: true,
              ticks: {
                display: false,
              },
              grid: {
                display: false,
              },
            },
            x: {
              display: false,
              ticks: {
                display: false,
              },
              grid: {
                display: false,
              },
            },
          },
          plugins: {
            legend: {
              display: false,
            },
          },
        },
        plugins: [pieLabelsLine],
      };

      // render init block
      const myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), config);
```

https://codepen.io/BillDou/pen/oNoGBXb

Answer (score 2):

The real problem lies with the overlapping of the labels when the slices are small.You can use [PieceLabel.js](https://emn178.github.io/Chart.PieceLabel.js/samples/demo/) which solves the issue of overlapping labels by hiding it . You mentioned that you **cannot hide labels** so use legends, which will display names of all slices

Or if you want exact behavior you can go with the [highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic), but it requires licence for commercial use.

```js
var randomScalingFactor = function() {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
};
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
var myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [
        250,
        30,
        5,
        4,
        2,

      ],
      backgroundColor: ['#ff3d67', '#ff9f40', '#ffcd56', '#4bc0c0', '#999999'],
      borderColor: 'white',
      borderWidth: 5,
    }]
  },
  showDatapoints: true,
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    },
    pieceLabel: {
      render: 'label',
      arc: true,
      fontColor: '#000',
      position: 'outside'
    },
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Testing',
      fontSize: 20
    },
    animation: {
      animateScale: true,
      animateRotate: true
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/emn178/Chart.PieceLabel.js/master/build/Chart.PieceLabel.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart-area"></canvas>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/zadn9j1j/1/) demo

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem is, that certain slices could have the same background color since these can be assigned by the users. This means that users can no longer distinguish which one which is.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved:
We add script to file global:

```
if(window.Chartist && Chartist.Pie && !Chartist.Pie.prototype.resolveOverlap) {
        Chartist.Pie.prototype.resolveOverlap = function() {
            this.on('draw', function(ctx) {
                if(ctx.type == 'label') {
                    let gText = $(ctx.group._node).find('text');
                    let ctxHeight = ctx.element.height();
                    gText.each(function(index, ele){
                        let item = $(ele);
                        let diff = ctx.element.attr('dy') - item.attr('dy');
                        if(diff == 0) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        if(Math.abs(diff) < ctxHeight) {
                            ctx.element.attr({dy: ctx.element.attr('dy') - ctxHeight});
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        };
    }
```

and then:

```
new Chartist.Pie(element, data, options).resolveOverlap();
```